# Magento2: Installing issue on MacBook Air

Tags: magento2, installation, macbook, php-extension

I m trying to install Magento2 in MacBook Air.
But having an issue of PHP extension
mcrypt
intl

Did all try to install this extension but not get success.
Please give me your suggestion if you faced the same thing on your mac.

Answer (score 0):

Depends a lot on what version of OSX you are running.  Also I'm assuming that you are running Magento 2 directly within the Macbook.  Or are you running within something installed on MacBook.  There are a lot of potential configurations.

Have you tried something like this?

https://gist.github.com/idleberg/24479f34dc5007e50d47

## Setup `php-mycrypt` on macOS (and versions of Mac OS X)

These steps should have been mentioned in the prerequisites of the [Laravel Installation Guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation), since I'm surely not the only person trying to get Laravel running on macOS.

### Install

Install Mcrypt using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/)

```
# PHP 7
brew install php70-mcrypt

# PHP 5
brew install php56-mcrypt --without-homebrew-php
```

Add this line to `/private/etc/php.ini`:

```
# PHP 7
extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php70-mcrypt/7.0.x/mcrypt.so"

# PHP 5
extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php56-mcrypt/5.6.x/mcrypt.so"
```

You are ready to go!

### Upgrade

Upgrade Mcrypt using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/)

```
brew reinstall -fs php71-mcrypt
```

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is using MAMP instead of the built in php server setup. I also faced issues with missing plugins but this was due to picking up the system default PHP version and not the one bundled with MAMP.